# Travelling with an Ecuadorian and Canadian passport

Tags: passports, dual-nationality

I am travelling to Costa Rica from Ecuador.  I have a Canadian and Ecuadorian passport.  I want to travel with both because I do not need a visa to enter Costa Rica if I use my Canadian passport.
Which passport number do I give the airline to buy my ticket? To leave and enter Ecuador I need to show them my Ecuadorian passport is that correct?  To enter and leave Costa Rica I would show my Canadian passport is that correct?
Do I ever show both passports?

Comment: I don't know the rules for Ecuador but in some places you are required to use the passport of that country when entering even if you're dual citizen